# some one stolen my all token from my smart contract

Tags: tokens

i build a application and i write a smart contract but someone steel my whole coin which is in smart contract but i didn't figure out what wrong in my smart contract.

its hash transaction where someone steel my token.
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x11697a258048f6b1fbb2cf56eabf5d8f56fc98b0cfc744038e66b316d2c93c9b
please help me to figure out what's going wrong.

here it my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

import "./SafeMath.sol";
import "./IERC20.sol";

contract xyzSmartContract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    string private _key;
    IERC20 public xyzToken;    
    address private owner;
   
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

  constructor(string memory key,address xyz_token)  {
        _key = key;
        xyzToken = IERC20(xyz_token);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function changeKey(string memory key) public onlyOwner {
        _key = key;
    }
    
    function get_xyz(address Member,string memory key,uint256 _amount)external {
        require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_key)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(key)), "invalid key");
        xyzToken.transfer(Member,_amount);
    }
    function get_xyz_owner()external onlyOwner{
            uint256 Balance=xyzToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        xyzToken.transfer(owner,Balance);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your smart contract?

Comment: From a disassembly, it looks like your contract stores tokens that can be unlocked with a password? In that case, the attacker simply grabbed the password from the contracts storage directly or from the transaction setting the password and took the tokens. Just never do that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your contract is relying on a password, which is set in the constructor. The password variable field is marked as *private*.

Nothing in Ethereum is private. All data is public. Using a contract variable which is marked as *private* doesn't mean nobody can read it - it only means external contracts can't read it.

It's quite easy to find the password either from 1) the deployment transaction arguments or 2) accessing the contract's storage directly.

Never store anything private in public Ethereum.

Comment: how they get my password from Ethereum storage although its private and its store it decoded formate

Comment: The storage data is all public, just not trivial to access. Here's a recent tool to inspect any  contract's storage - but it only works for Ethereum network. https://evm.storage/